# Convert string to date in specific format

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, date-parsing

How do I convert a string to a date type in SQL Server 2008 R2?

My string is formatted `dd/mm/yyyy`

I tried this

```
SELECT CAST('01/08/2014' AS DATE)
```

But that does the cast in `mm/dd/yyyy` format.

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for `convert()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the `convert` function, where you can specify a format code:

```
select convert(datetime, '01/08/2014', 103)
```

The `103` means dd/mm/yyyy. See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/ms187928.aspx).

Answer (score 5):

Dateformat.

```
SET DATEFORMAT DMY ;
SELECT cast('01/08/2014' as date) ;
```

Convert.

```
SELECT convert(date, '01/08/2014', 103 ) ;
```

And for completeness, SQL Server 2012 and later has the following.

```
SELECT parse('01/08/2014' as date using 'en-NZ' ) ;
```

Comment: I just realised that the asker and both answerers of this question are kiwis. Ka pai!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CAST before use FORMAT_DATE function. Please, see bellow.

SELECT FORMAT_DATE(CAST(yourcolumn AS date), 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS DateOfBirth

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

[TO_DATE](https://www.oraask.com/wiki/oracle-to-date) function in oracle is used to convert any character to date format.

for example :

```
SELECT to_date ('2019/03/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
FROM   dual;
```

[CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) function in SQL SERVER is used to converts an expression from one datatype to another datatype.

for example:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '01/08/2014', 103) date_convert;
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: The OP is about SQL Server. Pointing out the Oracle function for that task does not answer their question

Answer (score -2):

You can convert string to date easily by
SELECT CAST(YourDate AS DATE)